# Oracle ORA-14028: missing AT or VALUES keyword during SPLIT PARTITION to multiple dat

Tags: oracle, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm attempting to split a maxvalue partition (by date) and am  ORA-14028: missing AT or VALUES.  I tried adding a AT TO_DATE('01-JAN_2018) and still get the error.  Given VALUES is in the query any hints or direction is appreciated.
Code being used follows:

```
 ALTER TABLE HISTORY_TABLE SPLIT PARTITION DEFAULT_PARTITION INTO
 (
 PARTITION P2018Q1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2018','dd-MON-yyyy')),
 PARTITION P2018Q2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUL-2018','dd-MON-yyyy')),
 PARTITION P2018Q3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-OCT-2018','dd-MON-yyyy')),
 PARTITION P2018Q4 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019','dd-MON-yyyy')),
 PARTITION P2019Q1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2019','dd-MON-yyyy')),
 PARTITION P2019Q2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUL-2019','dd-MON-yyyy')),
 PARTITION P2019Q3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-OCT-2019','dd-MON-yyyy')),
 PARTITION P2019Q4 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2020','dd-MON-yyyy')),
 PARTITION P2020Q1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2020','dd-MON-yyyy')),
 PARTITION P2020Q2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUL-2020','dd-MON-yyyy')),
 PARTITION DEFAULT_PART2
 )
 UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears I am using 12c SQL on 11g causing the error.